# Tabulator responsiveCollapse icon always visual

Tags: tabulator

Is it possible to only show the responsiveCollapse icon when the width of the screen has been reduced enough that it actually contains some collapsed data.
Currently even when all the columns fit nicely on the screen, the first column still shows the responsiveCollapse icon for each row. Clicking on it obviously does nothing as no collapsed data.

```
{formatter:"responsiveCollapse", width:50, minWidth:0, align:"center", resizable:false, headerSort:false},
```

In comparison to the datatable js solution, they only show the expand icon when there is collapsed data to view. Please see attached screen shots

Is there any setting that could achieve this requirement?

Any help would be appreciated?

[Tabulator Screen Shot with no collapsed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMsti.png)

[Datatable Screen Shot with no collapsed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeINp.png)

[Datatable Screen Shot with collapsed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIQgj.png)

Answer (score 1):

As of the 4.5 release there is now a ***responsiveCollapse*** formatter that you can add to a column to insert a fully functional collapse toggle:

```
{formatter:"responsiveCollapse", headerSort:false}
```

A demo of it in action can be found [Here](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5#responsive-layout-collapse)

Check out the [Formatter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-module) for more information